# Count Iff [date] occured in the past 90 days ACCESS

Tags: date, ms-access, expression, builder

I'm having a bit of trouble.

I am trying to build a Access query that counts the number of times a product was consumed based on if the date occurred with in the past 90 days and the status of the product being consumed.

I attempted this for just counting the occurrences for the past 90 days.

```
90 Days Consumption: Count(IIf([Movement]![Date]>Date()+90,[Movement]![Product],0))
```

It did not work. I'm not really sure how to also add the condition of it being the consumed status along with the past 90 days.

Anything helps.

Comment: don't you need to subtract 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"past 90 days" is today-90

```
90 Days Consumption: Count(IIf([Movement]![Date]>Date()-90,[Movement]![Product],0))
```

You might need to be careful with using COUNT() here because this function counts ANY non-null as 1, so the IIF() can return zero, which is non-null. Perhaps this instead:

```
90 Days Consumption: Sum(IIf([Movement]![Date]>Date()-90,1,0))
```

Comment: I can't believe I was over looking a simple solution, sum and -90 did the trick! Thank you for your help :).